# Unknown Column In Where Clause With Join

Tags: mysql, sql, yii

I want to join 3 table one column sum has to be compare with another column

Here is my query

```
SELECT 
    *, `e`.`id` AS `event_ac_id`, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN trans.gift_transaction_status = 1 
               THEN trans.event_gift_amount  
               ELSE 0 END) as amount 
FROM 
    `tbl_event_category` `cat` 
LEFT JOIN 
    `tbl_event` `e` ON e.event_category = cat.id 
LEFT JOIN 
    `tbl_organisation` `org` ON e.organisation_id = org.id 
LEFT JOIN 
    `tbl_event_gift_transaction` `trans` ON e.id = trans.event_id 
WHERE 
    cat.type ='campaign' AND is_approved=1
    AND e.funding_goal_amount <= amount 
GROUP BY 
    `event_ac_id` 
LIMIT 8
```

> Exception (Database Exception) 'yii\db\Exception' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'amount' in
>   'where clause'

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand that SQL is evaluated from right to left. So when the MYSQL parser looks for `amount` column then it is not found and hence the error.

The [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html) says:

> "A select_expr can be given an alias using AS alias_name. The alias is
>   used as the expression's column name and can be used in GROUP BY,
>   ORDER BY, or HAVING clauses."

and

> Standard SQL doesn't allow you to refer to a column alias in a WHERE
>   clause. This restriction is imposed because when the WHERE code is
>   executed, the column value may not yet be determined.

You can try this:

```
SELECT *, `e`.`id` AS `event_ac_id`, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN trans.gift_transaction_status = 1 THEN trans.event_gift_amount  
   ELSE 0 END) as amount 
FROM `tbl_event_category` `cat` LEFT JOIN `tbl_event` `e` 
       ON e.event_category=cat.id 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_organisation` `org` ON e.organisation_id=org.id 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_event_gift_transaction` `trans` ON e.id=trans.event_id 
 WHERE cat.type ='campaign' 
 AND is_approved=1
 HAVING  e.funding_goal_amount <= amount
 GROUP BY `event_ac_id` LIMIT 8
```

Comment: i have tried `SUM(CASE WHEN trans.gift_transaction_status = 1 THEN trans.event_gift_amount  
ELSE 0 END)>e.funding_goal_amount` also Whats the solution for that

Comment: @KakulSarma:- Try to use the HAVING clause instead of the WHERE clause to use your condition.

Answer (score 2):

A computed value cannot be on the `WHERE` clause. Only actual columns need to be used there.

If you want to filter AFTERWARDS the `WHERE` clause has been executed, you can use the `HAVING` statement

Answer (score 1):

The filter on aggregate values is base on having

could be you need this

```
SELECT *, `e`.`id` AS `event_ac_id`, 
   SUM(CASE WHEN trans.gift_transaction_status = 1 THEN trans.event_gift_amount  
   ELSE 0 END) as amount 
FROM `tbl_event_category` `cat` LEFT JOIN `tbl_event` `e` 
       ON e.event_category=cat.id 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_organisation` `org` ON e.organisation_id=org.id 
LEFT JOIN `tbl_event_gift_transaction` `trans` ON e.id=trans.event_id 
 WHERE cat.type ='campaign' 
  AND is_approved=1
  HAVING  e.funding_goal_amount <= amount
  GROUP BY `event_ac_id` LIMIT 8
```